# Page Layout Assignment Insufficient Privilege?

Tags: profile, insufficient-privileges, privileges

What is the system permission to enable a profile to be able to assign page layouts for record types? I am receiving an insufficient privilege error when trying to save layout assignment changes as an Org DB Admin (read, one level under system admin).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Customize Application?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, I have customize application on my profile. However, the object I am trying to assign page layouts for is a custom object in a custom app, and there is a separate permission set to grant permissions to it. Now, I see that I need to modify the permission set and grant the 'customize app' setting under system permissions. Is this correct? --edit: I'm now assuming that system permissions in a permission set override profile level system permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@krewllobster you are correct that permission settings in a permission set do not override profile level access. Were you the original creator of the record types? Your profile "DB Admin" which sounds like a custom profile. It's possible that your profile was not granted access to the individual record types for the custom object.Go To Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > Object Settings > *Your Custom Object* and verify that you have access to each record type and not just the Default Master.